# Changing the array's base-address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, base-address

Why can't I modify the base address of an array? Is it because the allocated memory would be lost? in that case, I can make an array using a pointer and change what the pointer points to and the allocated memory would be lost too, then what is the difference?

Comment: The code has been compiled assuming you can't change the base address (because you can't); it makes no assumptions about what stupid things you do with pointers to your own allocations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell some background information what you want to achieve. What do you mean with "modify the base address of an array"? If you allocate the memory, the base address is in the allocated memory block. Changing a pointer to an address outside the array will result in undefined behavior when you try to access the data where the pointer points to.

Comment: Why would you need to change the address of an array?

Comment: FYI, array's are not pointers.

Comment: And how would you do that? There is no possible syntax to change the address of **any** object, array or not.

Comment: Think about a house. You can't change the address of the house, you need to move it from one place to another, brick by brick. Array is an object in memory, if you want it to be in another place you need enough space in this another place, and then copy the array to there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are objects all on their own, and not pointers. Consider a simpler object:

```
int a = 0;
```

Would you expect to be able to change its address? Of course not. An object is a region of storage with a type. The region of storage is identified by its address, so you won't expect to change it. And arrays are objects too. When you declare

```
int b[8] = {0};
```

you declare an object, the size of eight integers, that will occupy some storage. You can't change its address any more than you can change the address of any single int.

You have probably been told that arrays are pointers. But they are not! They may be converted, even implicitly, to a pointer more often than not, but they are still object types. Pointers often stand in for arrays because the address of the first element is enough to reach any other element with pointer arithmetic, but the pointer is not the array object itself. The difference becomes apparent when you inspect their object properties. For instance:

```
sizeof(b) != sizeof(int*)
```

The object `b` is not the size of a pointer, indeed it is the size of 8 integers, likely larger than a pointer.

Comment: Also, there's no syntax in C to change the address of *any* object. It's not like you can change the address of some of them but not of others.

Comment: @NikosC.: The syntax and grammar would allow changing the address of any object; `&b = foo;` would do it. This is prohibited by the semantics, specifically by the constraint in C 2018 6.5.16 2: “An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.”

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thank You so much, but I have one last question when we define a parameter in a function as an array (int arr[]) can we consider it as a pointer there? I know that when we pass an array to a function the address is passed, but I mean that size of that parameter wouldn't be the size of the array and we can assign any other array to this parameter inside the function.

Comment: @ASF - You cannot define a function to take an array. When declaring ` (int arr[])` the compiler already adjusts it to a pointer `(int *arr)`. The function can only take a pointer. Passing arrays as arguments is one of the places where implicit conversions occur, as I mentioned before.